# @Delegate class without default constructor

Tags: groovy

How can I create a delegate class in Groovy for a class which doesn't have a default constructor? I would like to decorate JUnit's ResultPrinter but am getting an error about the missing constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your issue.  I just tried this with Java's `Short` — which also does not have a default constructor.

Everything worked as expected, except if you didn't initialize the delegated object, you get an NPE.

Is it possible you are [using `@Delegate` incorrectly](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Delegate+transformation)?  Delegate doesn't decorate existing classes, it allows you to use an existing classes methods in your own class.  It's like `extend`, but without the class inheritance.

Example code:

```
class Foo {
    @Delegate Short num
    String bar
    String toString() { "$bar: $num" }
}

def f = new Foo(bar: 'bob', num: 34 as Short)
println f // OK
println f.doubleValue() // OK

f = new Foo()
println f.doubleValue() // NPE
```

(Alternatively, providing some useful information, such as the actual error and stacktrace, and example code, will get you more useful responses.)