# use delegate annotation + extends for groovy class without default constructor call

Tags: inheritance, groovy, interface, delegates, annotations

So I have the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867323/delegate-class-without-default-constructor) and [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Delegate-a-class-without-a-default-constructor-td5710078.html). I have classes `A` and `B`. `A` shall be decorated by `B`. To save my some typing, I use the `@delegate` groovy annotation so that groovy handles all the calls to `B`s methods and automatically deligates them to an `A` type object that is saved in `B`.

This works fine, however I do not get any help from compiler. If I try `myB.someMethodOfClassA()` then the compiler is not smart enough to figure out, that this method call will be delegated to `A` and that such a method is present in `A`, so it marks it as not found - at runtime it will still work.

I can workaround that by having `B` also extends from `A`. However, then `A`s default-constructor is called when initializing B and if there is none, it fails of course.

One (clean) solution would be to create an `AInterface` and let `A` and `B` implement it. Is there another (clean) way of doing what I want without having to create an interface all the time? (I might even not be able to do that if `A` is not under my control)

Here is an example with inheritation:

```
public class OldClass {
    public String name
    public OldClass(String name) { this.name = name }
    public sayHello() { println "hello $name" }
}
```

The following class should be able to be used like the oldClass but add another method

```
public class NewClass {
    @Delegate OldClass delegationForOldClass

    public NewClass(String name) { this.delegationForOldClass = new OldClass(name) }
    public sayGoodbye() { println "byebye" }
}
```

I can now use it like this:

```
NewClass myNewClass = NewClass("James")
myNewClass.sayHello() //prints "hello James" because the @Delegation annotation delegates the call to the OldClass object
myNewClass.sayGoodbye() //prints "bye"
```

So it compiles and works at runtime even though I am not extending the `OldClass` here because of the annotation. However the IDE compiler complains (at compile time) when I go for `myNewClass.sayHello()` that `sayHello` might not be there. He also does not tell me this method when using code completion. So to be able to use code completion I can do it like that:

```
public class NewClass extends OldClass {
    @Delegate OldClass delegationForOldClass

    public newClass(String name) { this.delegationForOldClass = new OldClass(name) }
    public sayGoodbye() { println "byebye" }
}
```

This however only works of `OldClass` has an empty constructor. But it doesn't, it has only a constructor which takes a string. So groovy tries to call the default constructor because of the extends keyword (it is the same in java right?) and of course fails. If I add an defaul constructor to `OldClass` then it will work, but I don't want to do that.

Is there any way to work around this behaviour?

Comment: what compiler are you talking about?  do you have errors/exception/...?

Comment: Maybe an example would help?

Comment: @cfrick, I use the 2.3 groovy compiler. @ tim_yates I'll contribute an example soon.

Comment: I now added an example, hope it helps. =)

Comment: Looks like you have an IDE problem, not a Groovy problem. What IDE are you using ?

Comment: Probably. Im using Eclipse 4.2.2 with the latest groovy plugin.